# GIS software with Bayesian Network capabilities

Tags: plugins, integration

I am looking for any GIS software that has Bayesian Network capabilities.  Ideally I'd be able to define grid layers as discrete or continuous inputs in to the network and then be able to produce layers based on the predictions of given nodes.  I note there are several academic papers that seem to use a variety of different GIS and Bayesian tools but there doesn't seem to be any mention of an integrated solution.  I'm starting to think that a solution doesn't exist and I'm going to hack my own solution together.

Answer (score 3):

A tool created for ArcGIS has been done by the University of Queensland and Norsys : (this is a bit dated as was using  ArcGIS 9.2)

> This is a simple example for a model of land surface stability. The BN
>   classification tool categorizes nodes as: background, classification
>   and observation variables. In the figure above, the three BN variables
>   for slope, soil and wetness index are influential factors (background
>   variables) used to derive (classification variable) slope stability.
>   The direct consequences of slope instability may be observed
>   (observation variable) from surface failures such as soil creep or
>   slips. The tool is designed to interpret classification problems
>   following this generic structure, we believe many problems fit this
>   form.

Norsys software was used:

http://www.norsys.com/netica.html

includes a free demo - http://www.norsys.com/netica.html#free

You can contact the University of Queensland for an update on the subject

http://www.gpem.uq.edu.au/cser-tools-bngis

http://www.gpem.uq.edu.au/contact-us

Comment: Thanks, I am already familiar with Netica but hadn't managed to hit upon the plugin from UQ.  I've contacted them to get a copy of it but I don't think it will do exactly what I want as it seems to be limited to outputting Bayesian Classifications. It is a good start tho. Thanks again.

Comment: MapWindow has this:"Bayesian Analysis Plugin using SMILE A plugin to visually display and analyze spatially-oriented bayesian decision networks by associating nodes with GIS spatial locations in a point shape file."http://www.mapwindow.org/apps/wiki/doku.php?id=download

Comment: Lewis - mapwindow with the SMILE plugin looks promising!  I've used Genie and SMILE before and while they don't do exactly what I want they are still pretty good and close to what I need so I'll defintely check it out.  It is great that mapwindow is open source as well as I may be able to make the modifications I need and resubmit it to the project.